# Water as a conductor and bubbles

Tags: current, water

I tried putting two extremities of a 6 volts battery into water.
With salty water, bubbles appear close to the positive end.

With unsalted water, what looks like a thin white foam starts to squirt from the positive and and moves through the bottom of the glass.

What am I seeing there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing the [Electrolysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolysis). Namely, separation of water into hydrogen and oxygen.
Salty water is conducting better than a non-salty one, so you see a stronger reaction in it. But the non-salty one is still impure (it still has some minerals dissolved), so some conductivity exist in it too, but the reaction is weaker.

Comment: Why do hydrogen and oxygen separate when electrons flow into water?  Is that the energy released by the current, if that makes any sense?
Also, why does that happen strictly close to the positive terminal?

Comment: The exact physics/chemistry of the process is out of my competence. Please take a look at the Wiki link I provided, it might give some insights.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe this was a question better suited for the "physics" stack exchange rather than this.

Comment: You can find more questions about Electrolysis on https://chemistry.stackexchange.com

Comment: BTW, it's hydrogen on the positive terminal and oxygen on the negative. You will see more hydrogen than oxygen generated (by volume) because of their proportions in the water. Also the oxygen electrode is going to get oxidized quickly, so if you use something like iron nails you will quickly see a green goo appearing..

Comment: @EugeneSh. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolysis_of_water) on the subject says the opposite. I am inclined to believe the Wiki page because I know that hydrogen ions (a.k.a., "protons") in water are positively charged, and so they would naturally migrate toward the negative terminal.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I will not argue with Wiki. Was relying on my memories from couple of decades ago...

Comment: Oxidation is at the anode and reduction at the cathode. In electrolysis, which is what this is, the cathode is the negative terminal and hydrogen gas is released as hydronium ions are reduced. At the anode, you either get oxygen gas, produced by oxidizing water, or chlorine gas, produced by oxidizing chloride ions, if you have sufficiently salty water.